# Full Text search working unexpectedly

Tags: mysql

DB structure is like this:

```
no|brand|name

1|vim|one
2|vim|two
3|vimal|three
```

My query to search full text on this table is this:

```
$words[0]='vim';
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (name,brand) AGAINST
('*".$words[0]."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

It returns only third row with brand value as `vimal` & no above two rows are returned where as it should return all three rows.

Like query works fine though `like %$words[0]%`.

Can anyone tell why full text search is not working okay or ami I missing something here?

Comment: Also are you on mysiam or innodb?

Comment: Well I found a solution to that, variable `ft_min_word_len` is set to 4 & my brand name word is of length 3.And that happens with every 3 letter word.

Comment: Post it as your own answer to solve the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings in mysql `ft_min_word_len` is set to 4 by default & thus is not able to search for a product with length of 3.
Changing that setting will resolve the issue.